# insert the last status of a service of users to another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Database and insert service activation log for all users. for example: service a is deactivate for mike today then activate for him tomorrow and then deactivate again. i need to have the last status of each service for users in another table. (unique constraint: userid,serviceid)

```
logid  |  userid     |  serviceid  |  status
-------+-------------+-------------+--------
1      |  mike       |      a      |      0
2      |  mike       |      b      |      1
3      |  mike       |      b      |      0
4      |  mike       |      a      |      1
5      |  Dave       |      c      |      1
6      |  Dave       |      a      |      0
7      |  mike       |      d      |      1
8      |  mike       |      c      |      1
9      |  mike       |      a      |      0
```

for example: in above table, i need to have the following table:

```
userid     |  serviceid  |  laststatus
-------+-------------+-------------+--------
mike       |      a      |      0
mike       |      b      |      0
mike       |      c      |      1
mike       |      d      |      1
Dave       |      c      |      1
Dave       |      a      |      0
```

Is there any while loop to read all records from table1 and insert or update table2 to store the last status of each service for users? like this:

```
while (select * from table1)
{
  IF EXISTS    
    (
    SELECT 1   
    FROM table2 
    where table2.userid=table1.userid and table2.serviceid=table1.serviceid
        )    
    BEGIN
      UPDATE table2  
      SET  table2.laststatus = table1.status 
      WHERE table2.userid=@userid and table2.serviceid=table1.serviceid
    END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ( table1.userid  ,table1.serviceid ,table1.status  )
}
```

Last status is the status with largest logid for a given user and service

Comment: Last status is the status with largest `logid` for a given user and service?

Comment: the question isn't clear..try using `Row_number()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a `MERGE` statement, like so:

```
merge table2 as tgt
using
(
 select * from table1 
 where logid in
 (
  --Get the row which has the last status for that user-service combination
  select distinct max(logid) over (partition by userid, serviceid order by userid,serviceid) mid 
  from table1)
) as src
on tgt.userid = src.userid and tgt.serviceid = src.serviceid
when matched then
update
set tgt.[status] = src.[status]
when not matched then
insert (userid,serviceid, [status])
values(src.userid, src.serviceid, src.[status]);
```

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/MZPH40248).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a Datetime column on table1 as dt. how can i use max(dt) Instead of max(logid)?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `INSERT` Trigger on Table1 which would update your Table2.

The trigger would update `laststatus` of Table2. You can get the last status of a particular user like this:

```
declare @status int
select  top 1 @status = status from Table1 where userid = 'dave' and serviceid = 'c' 
order by logid desc
select @status
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: A trigger's not necessary.

Comment: Without using trigger you will need to have a continuous running process which would be polling the table. IMO this activating/deactivating the services will not be so frequent that a separate process should be running to poll the table and a small trigger would not be an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code will bring you the results you are looking for.
With the below code you will insert all records from table1 in table2, I don't know if this is the scenario you are looking for. Otherwise you could combine it with a `MERGE` statement as @shree.pat18 suggests.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
 SELECT
   userid
  ,serviceid
  ,status
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, serviceid ORDER BY logid DESC) Rnk
 FROM table1
)
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT
  userid
 ,serviceid
 ,status AS laststatus
FROM cte
WHERE Rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

No triggers necessary. No merges necessary. No `partition by` or other crazy stuff necessary.

```
insert into my_second_table (userid, serviceid, laststatus)
select t1.userid, t1.serviceid, t2.status
from (
  select userid, serviceid, max(logid) as lastlogid
  from my_first_table
  group by userid, serviceid
) as t1
join my_first_table t2 on t1.lastlogid = t2.logid
```

Comment: @shree.pat18: This is by far the hard part. I'm sure he can figure that out. :)  Heck, just delete all records and insert again.

Comment: Would you recommend delete and insert again for a table with 100K records? :P

Comment: @shree.pat18: Yes. :P